# Python: object variable vs standalone variable

Tags: python, object, dictionary

I'm writing a stack class `MyStack`, implemented as a list, where each element is a dictionary with two fields (`'a'` and `'b'`). Each of these dictionary fields is itself a list (initialized as empty lists in `push()`). Apart from `push()` and `pop()` (the latter skipped for readability here) I intend to `add` elements to these lists (the dictionary fields) for the element at the top of the stack (index `[-1]`).

The problem is the value gets added to both dictionary fields, not just the selected one. However, I then test this with a standalone variable,`standalone_stack` ,that I test is identical to the `stack` variable of object `MyStack`. Surprisingly, I get what I want - I append only to the selected field. Here's the code:

```
 class MyStack(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.stack = []

    def push(self):
        self.stack.append(dict.fromkeys(['a', 'b'], []))

    def add(self, field, value):
        self.stack[-1][field].append(value)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.stack)

def lists_the_same(list1, list2):
    if list1 == list2:
        print 'Yes, the same'
    else:
        print 'No, not the same'

# Create essentially the same data in two different ways:
ms = MyStack()
standalone_stack = [{'a': [], 'b': []}]
ms.push()
print ms
print standalone_stack
lists_the_same(ms.stack, standalone_stack)

# Now modify both:
field = 'a'
value = 2
ms.add(field=field, value=value)
standalone_stack[-1][field].append(value)
print ms
print standalone_stack
lists_the_same(ms.stack, standalone_stack)
```

My output with Python 2.7.6 is below:

```
[{'a': [], 'b': []}]
[{'a': [], 'b': []}]
Yes, the same
[{'a': [2], 'b': [2]}]
[{'a': [2], 'b': []}]
No, not the same
```

What I need help with is:

- Why there's this odd difference in behavior when the same list is a field of an object (`self.stack`) or a standalone variable `standalone_stack`? Even pointing out Python related keywords would help, since I'm not able to google this out for some time already.
- If I could make my question more clear. This is my first post here.
- Maybe I'm thinking about this backwards and you'd implement this differently, possibly in a more Pythonic way.

Comment: `dict.fromkeys(['a', 'b'], [])` creates a dictionary with *one shared list*, not separate copies. Use `{'a': [], 'b': []}`.

Comment: Thanks Martijn Pieters, that was quick. This is exactly what I was looking for.